# Welcher Satz ist richtig? Subjekt oder Objekt

Tags: grammatical-case

Welcher Satz ist richtig? Und warum?

> 1. Danach hat mich mein Chef angerufen.
> 2. Danach hat mein Chef mich angerufen.

Comment: Why do you think (only) one sentence is right or one sentence must be wrong?

Comment: Ich denke, dass ein Satz grammatikalisch falsch ist!

Comment: Was ist mit "Subjekt oder Objekt" im Titel gemeint? Und warum genau denkst Du, dass ein Satz falsch ist? Entschuldige, ich will nicht nerven, nur genau verstehen, was das Problem ist.

Comment: Weil das Subjekt (mein Chef) nach dem Verb (hat) immer Platz nehmen soll, wenn die erste Stelle im Satz für das Subject nicht möglich ist.

Comment: if that was the case, why consider the other (first) sentence?

Comment: @infinitezero: Diese Frage wurde in einem Deutsch-Forum in deutscher Sprache gestellt. Der Fragesteller hat bisher sämtliche anderen Fragen auch nur in deutscher Sprache gestellt. Er antwortet auf Kommentare ebenfals nur auf Deutsch. Warum glaubst du, mit ihm in einer Fremdsprache kommunizieren zu müssen, von der du nicht einmal wisst, ob er sie beherrscht, während du sicher sein kannst, dass er Deutsch versteht?

Comment: @planetmaker: Der an infinitezero gerichtete Kommentar gilt auch für dich.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast force of habit, I frankly didn't even realise it. mea culpa.

Comment: @infinitezero: Auch mit mir kannst du ruhig auf Deutsch kommunizieren. Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache und Englisch ist für mich eine Fremdsprache, die ich zwar gut beherrsche, aber bei weitem nicht auf demselben Niveau wie Deutsch. Latein war zwar ein Fach in dem ich bei meiner Matura geprüft wurde, es ist aber auch das Fach das schuld daran war, dass ich zur Matura ein zweites Mal antreten musste. Und seit meiner Matura (1983) habe ich Latein nie wieder gebraucht. (Österr. Schweiz, Liechtenstein, Südtirol: die Matura/Maturität (die Reife); nur Deutschland: das Abitur (das Davongehen))

Comment: Können wir uns darauf einigen nicht jedes Mal eine halbe Dissertation mit missionarischen Eifer zu verfassen, wenn wer aus Versehen in der "falschen" Sprache antwortet? Insbesondere, wenn es Kommentare betrifft?

Comment: @planetmaker: Können wir uns stattdessen bitte lieber darauf einigen, sowohl in Antworten als auch in Kommentaren nach Möglichkeit gleich die richtige Sprache zu verwenden? Dann entsteht nämlich gar keine Notwendigkeit, darauf hinzuweisen.

Comment: Den Kommentar von infintezero hast Du gesehen? Insofern unterlass doch bitte die Unterstellung, dass die Leute immer in böser Absicht handeln und spar die Energie  für gute Antworten auf.

Comment: @planetmaker: Wann genau habe ich deiner Meinung nach irgendjemandem irgendwelche Absichten unterstellt? Wie kommst du dazu, mir so etwas zu unterstellen? Davon abgesehen muss ich keine Energien aufsparen. Ich habe bisher mehr als 1800 Antworten geschrieben und dafür eine Reputation von mehr als 100.000 Punkten erreicht. Da kann ich ruhig auch mal etwas Energie dafür aufwenden, andere an die Regeln zu erinnern.

Answer (score 1):

### Subjekt oder Objekt

In beiden Sätzen ist *»mein Chef«* das Subjekt, denn der Satz ist ein Aktiv-Satz und in deutschen Aktivsätzen ist der Täter immer das Subjekt. Außerdem ist *»mein Chef«* der einzige Teil des Satzes, der im Nominativ steht. Der Nominativ ist exklusiv für das Subjekt reserviert. Eine Ausnahme ist nur der Gleichsetzungsnominativ (»Hans ist *Arzt*«) der aber nur auftreten kann, wenn der Satz ein gleichsetzendes Verb (*»ist«, »wird«, »bleibt«*) enthält, was hier nicht der Fall ist.

Der Satz enthält ein Akkusativ-Objekt. Es beschreibt auf wen die Handlung des Satzes eine Wirkung hat, das ist das Personalpronomen *»mich«.*

Es enthalten also beide Sätze sowohl ein Subjekt als auch ein Objekt. Daher ist mir nicht ganz klar, warum in der Überschrift der Frage »Subjekt oder Objekt« steht. Was auch immer der Grund dafür gewesen sein mag, ich hoffe, das ist jetzt geklärt.

### Welcher Satz ist richtig?

Es sind alle Sätze richtig.

Warum? Weil die deutsche Grammatik sehr flexibel ist was die Reihenfolge der Bestandteile eines Satzes betrifft. Deutsch setzt beim Identifizieren der Bestandteile vor allem auf grammatische Merkmale, wie z.B. den grammatischen Fall. Die Reihenfolge spielt eine deutlich untergeordnete Rolle und wird eher dafür verwendet, einzelne Bestandteile hervorzuheben.

Folgende Sätze sind korrekt:

> 1. Danach hat mich mein Chef angerufen.
> 2. Danach hat mein Chef mich angerufen.
> 3. Mein Chef hat mich danach angerufen.
> 4. Mein Chef hat danach mich angerufen.
> 5. Mich hat mein Chef danach angerufen.
> 6. Mich hat danach mein Chef angerufen.

Das finite Verb (jenes Verb, das gebeugt wird, um mit dem Subjekt in Person und Zahl übereinzustimmen) steht in deutschen Aussagesätzen immer an Position 2. Im vorliegenden Satz ist das das Hilfsverb *»hat«* (eine Form von *»haben«*). Alle anderen Verben liegen in der infiniten Form vor (also nicht nach Person und Zahl gebeugt) und stehen am Ende des Satzes. Das ist hier das Wort *»angerufen«,* das ist das Partizip II des Verbs *»anrufen«.*

Alle anderen Bestandteile (Subjekt *»mein Chef«,* Akkusativobjekt *»mich«,* adverbiale Ergänzung *»danach«*) können (zumindest in diesem Beispiel) beliebig angeordnet werden.

Die unterschiedlichen Reihenfolgen erlauben es, in bestimmten Situationen hervorzuheben, dass man *mich* (und nicht jemand anderen) angerufen hat, oder dass der Anruf *danach* (und nicht davor oder währenddessen) erfolgt ist. Um das zu erreichen stellt man jenen Bestandteil des Satzes, das man hervorheben möchte, an eine Stelle, an der er in der Standardreihung nicht stehen würde.